# how to extract specific integers in a mixed string-integer line in c++

Tags: c++, string

I am reading a text file in c++, this is example of some lines in it:

```
remove 1 2 cost 13.4
```

How could I disregard all things except two integers after remove, "1" and "2" and put them in two integer variable?

my incomplete code:

```
ifstream file("input.txt");
string line;
int a, b;

if(file.is_open())
{
   while (!file.eof())
   {
      getline (file, line);
      istringstream iss(line);
      if (line.find("remove") != string::npos)
      {     

          iss >> a >> b;      // this obviously does not work, not sure how to
                              // write the code here
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: I saw `!file.eof()` and made a weird noise.

Comment: yeah, I copied the framework of code from elsewhere, it may have problems like you said, but it is not important here, I have another question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few options:

1. Use the `stringstream` created for the line to find the `remove` token and parse the next two integers. In other words, replace this:

   ```
   if (line.find("remove") != string::npos)
   {     

       iss >> a >> b;      // this obviously does not work, not sure how to
                           // write the code here
   }
   ```

   with this:

   ```
   string token;
   iss >> token;

   if (token == "remove")
   {
       iss >> a >> b;
   }
   ```
2. Create a `stringstream` for the rest of the line (`6` is the length of the "remove" token).

   ```
   string::size_type pos = line.find("remove");

   if (pos != string::npos)
   {     
       istringstream iss(line.substr(pos + 6));

       iss >> a >> b;
   }
   ```
3. Call the `seekg` method on the line `stringstream` to set the input position indicator of the stream after the "remove" token.

   ```
   string::size_type pos = line.find("remove");

   if (pos != string::npos)
   {     
       iss.seekg(pos + 6);

       iss >> a >> b;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot that's great and works. but I have other lines that have not the remove, they are like simply "4 5". what should I do for saving them?

Comment: @Omid I added other options to achieve the same thing. I would recommend option #3.